# Multiple monitors on different GPUs. Parrot OS (Debian)

Tags: debian, drivers, multi-monitor, amd-graphics, parrotsec

I am trying to set up dual monitors using both my integrated graphics card. I have a AMD Ryzen 5 3400G with an integrated Radeon Vega 11, and a dedicated AMD Radeon RX 6600. I've already tested everything on windows and it works just fine, having each monitor each GPU. However, when I boot up Parrot OS (very debian based, I still haven't found debian packages not compatible with Parrot), it disables one of the graphics cards, or refuses to display to them for some reason. If I leave both monitors connected, the integrated GPU works, but not the dedicated one. If I unplug the monitor from the integrated GPU and then boot up the system, then the dedicated GPU works fine, but if I plug the monitor back in, it doesn't wake up the integrated GPU. Another weird thing that happens, is that if I leave both monitors in, during the system splash they both work! I can see the Parrot splash on both monitors, but then when it goes away, both monitors turn off, and only the one on the integrated GPU turns back on.

I have tried to install all the drivers I've found. None of these have done the job:

```
xserver-xorg-video-radeon
xserver-xorg-video-ati
xserver-xorg-video-amdgpu
ricks-amdgpu-utils
amdgpu-installer
```

On the case of `amdgpu-installer`, I have some more info on what exactly happened with it:

```
$sudo amdgpu-install 
[sudo] password for kolterdyx: 
Hit:1 https://deb.parrot.sh/parrot lts InRelease
Hit:2 https://deb.parrot.sh/parrot parrot InRelease                   
Hit:3 https://deb.parrot.sh/direct/parrot parrot-security InRelease   
Hit:4 https://deb.parrot.sh/parrot parrot-backports InRelease
Hit:5 https://repo.radeon.com/amdgpu/22.20/ubuntu focal InRelease
Hit:6 https://repo.radeon.com/rocm/apt/5.2 ubuntu InRelease
Reading package lists... Done
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
linux-headers-6.0.0-2parrot1-amd64 is already the newest version (6.0.2-1parrot1).
linux-headers-6.0.0-2parrot1-amd64 set to manually installed.
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libelf-dev : Depends: libelf1 (= 0.183-1) but 0.187-1~bpo11+1 is to be installed
 rocm-llvm : Depends: libstdc++-5-dev but it is not installable or
                      libstdc++-7-dev but it is not installable
             Depends: libgcc-5-dev but it is not installable or
                      libgcc-7-dev but it is not installable
             Recommends: gcc-multilib but it is not going to be installed
             Recommends: g++-multilib but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Here's what `xrandr` tells me when I get the dedicated GPU to work:

```
Screen 0: minimum 320 x 200, current 3840 x 2160, maximum 16384 x 16384
DisplayPort-0 disconnected primary (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DisplayPort-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DisplayPort-2 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
HDMI-A-0 connected 3840x2160+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 600mm x 340mm
   3840x2160     60.00*+  50.00    59.94    30.00    30.00    25.00    24.00    29.97    23.98  
   2560x1440     59.95  
   1920x1200     60.00  
   1920x1080     60.00    50.00    59.94    30.00    24.00    29.97    23.98  
   1600x1200     60.00  
   1680x1050     60.00  
   1600x900      60.00  
   1280x1024     60.02  
   1440x900      60.00  
   1280x800      59.91  
   1280x720      60.00    59.94  
   1024x768      60.00  
   800x600       60.32  
   720x576       50.00  
   720x480       60.00    59.94  
   640x480       60.00    59.94
```

Here's what it says when I leave both monitors in (and only the one on the integrated card works)

```
Screen 0: minimum 320 x 200, current 1280 x 1024, maximum 16384 x 16384
HDMI-A-1 disconnected primary (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DisplayPort-3 connected 1280x1024+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 376mm x 301mm
   1280x1024     60.02*+  75.02  
   1280x800      60.02  
   1152x864      75.00  
   1280x720      60.02  
   1024x768      75.03    70.07    60.00  
   832x624       74.55  
   800x600       72.19    75.00    60.32    56.25  
   640x480       75.00    72.81    66.67    59.94  
   720x400       70.08
```

Here's what `lshw -c video` says:

```
  *-display                 
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: Navi 23
       vendor: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI]
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:03:00.0
       version: c7
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm pciexpress msi vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
       configuration: driver=amdgpu latency=0
       resources: irq:90 memory:e0000000-efffffff memory:f0000000-f01fffff ioport:f000(size=256) memory:fc900000-fc9fffff memory:fca00000-fca1ffff
  *-display
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: Picasso
       vendor: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI]
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:0b:00.0
       version: c8
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm pciexpress msi msix vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
       configuration: driver=amdgpu latency=0
       resources: irq:64 memory:c0000000-cfffffff memory:d0000000-d01fffff ioport:d000(size=256) memory:fc800000-fc87ffff memory:c0000-dffff
```

So now, with this info laid out, I reiterate my question:

How can I get both GPUs to work at the same time under Parrot OS?